# Get file from AWS-S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular4-forms, s3-bucket, uint8array

I have files(PDF and Image) in S3 bucket, and I am trying to download using

```
bucket.getObject(params, function(err, data)
```

I am getting the data in Uint8Array, How can I get it as a file??

in AWS properties of that file:

```
Content-Disposition : inline
Content-Type : application/pdf
```

**Code:**

```
const params = {
  Bucket: 'mts-test-procedure-document',
  Key: 'Key'

};

bucket.getObject(params, function(err, data){
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error getting your file: ', err);
    return false;
  }

  console.log('Successfully got file.', data);
  // return true;
});
```

**Console:**

```
Body: Uint8Array(94832) [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 51, 13, 10, 37, 129, 150, 189, 221, 13, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 13, 10, 60, 60, 32, 47, 84, 121, 112, 101, 32, 47, 67, 97, 116, 97, 108, 111, 103, 13, 10, 47, 80, 97, 103, 101, 115, 32, 50, 32, 48, 32, 82, 13, 10, 47, 79, 117, 116, 108, 105, 110, 101, 115, 32, 51, 32, 48, 32, 82, 13, 10, 62, 62, 13, 10, 101, 110, 100, 111, 98, 106, 13, 10, 52, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 13, 10, 60, 60, 47, …]
ContentType: "application/pdf"
LastModified: Wed Sep 26 2018 15:34:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
Metadata: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define while uploading your file .
For image

```
    Content-Type: "image/jpeg"
```

for jpeg images

For pdf:

```
 Content-Type: "application/pdf"
 Content-Disposition: inline;
```

More content -type can be found at https://s3browser.com/features-content-mime-types-editor.aspx

Comment: I have changed it for already existing file in S3, still it comes in Body:Uint8Array and ContentType: "application/pdf"